# Reactive contents problem in for loops for R Shiny

Tags: r, for-loop, shiny, rstudio, reactive

I am working on "for loops" in RShiny, I want to plot its result according to selected date. However, I have difficulty in determining reactive contents in server. It didn't worked. Here is my complete code:

```
dat <- read.csv('C:/Users/10109/Desktop/Alarm/alarm_plant5.CSV',header=T, sep=";")
dat=subset(dat, select = c("SourceName","EventTime" ,"Date"))
dat$Date <- format(as.Date(dat$Date, format = "%m.%d.%Y"), "%Y-%m-%d")

dat$EventTime= paste(dat$Date, dat$Time, sep=" ")
dat$EventTime=as.POSIXct(strptime( dat$EventTime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), tz = "", origin = '1970-01-01 00:00') 



ui <- fluidPage( 

  titlePanel("Analiz"),


  dateRangeInput(inputId="daterange", label = "Tarih" , start = "2017-01-02", end = "2017-12-31", min = "2017-01-02",
                 max = "2017-12-31",  separator = " to "),


   verbatimTextOutput("alarmsayisi"),


    plotOutput(outputId = "floodplot")


)


server <- function(input, output){

  training=reactive({dat%>% filter(as.Date(dat$Date)>=as.Date(input$daterange[1]) & as.Date(dat$Date)<=as.Date(input$daterange[2])  )}) 

  t=0
  result=reactive(data.frame())

  for (i in seq(reactive(nrow(training())))){
    limit2=reactive(training()$EventTime[i]+ minutes(10))
    flood_test=reactive(training()%>% filter(training()$EventTime[i] <= training()$EventTime & training()$EventTime <= limit2()))
    alarm_number=reactive(nrow(flood_test()))
    t=t+1 
    result[t,1]=reactive(i)

    result[t,2]=reactive(input[[training()$EventTime[i]]])
    result[t,3]=reactive(input[[alarm_number()]])
  }


  result()=result()[!duplicated(result()$V2),] 


  output$floodplot <- renderPlot({ 


    plot(result()$V2, result()$V3, type="l", col= "blue", xlab = "Tarih zaman", ylab = "On dakika icinde calan alarm sayisi",
         main = "Alarm flood tahmini") 
    abline(h=10, col="red",  lwd=1.5)


  }   ) 


  output$alarmsayisi <- renderText({
    paste("Toplam alarm sayisi", as.character(nrow(training())))
  })




}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The errors I encountered are:

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() :
Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

Or

```
  Error in result()[t, 1] = i : invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
```

I did many trials by changing the variables to reactive or not, but I could not make it work. Could you please help me about this issue? There should be something I interpret wrong.

Comment: Could you please be more informative? which values do you mean? actually I tried many versions by assigning values to reactive and not reactive. Unfortunately it didn't work. Maybe you can come with a solution?

Comment: Thank you for your interest to my question. I already look to the tutorials. I am not an expert in shiny that is why I could not figure out where my error is on this code. I posted my question to get advice of the experts about my errors in this code not to rewrite the code. Please do not comment to my post again if you don't have any specific useful advice on my question. Best,

Comment: Please post a fully reproducible example, including `ui.r, server.r, runApp()` and the underlying data. The issue here is as the error suggests, you cannot access a reactive variable, `(training,result)` outside of a reactive context. A reactive context being `observe,observeEvent,Eventreactive,renderxxx`.

Comment: where are you defining your `dat` ?

Comment: dat is my overall database in background, it is non-reactive

Comment: I uploaded my full code